# Displaying a horizontal rule at constant value in Vega-Lite, does not show up

Tags: vega-lite

I am trying to display a horizontal rule at a constant value in Vega-Lite, without success. Here is the code (can be pasted in https://vega.github.io/editor/#/):

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",

  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "ts", "type": "temporal"},
    "y": {"field": "a", "type": "quantitative"}
  },

  "layer": [
    {
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {"ts": "2021-11-26", "a": 0.16},
          {"ts": "2021-11-28", "a": 0.12}
        ]
      },
      "mark": { "type": "point" }
    },

    {
      "data": { "values": [] },
      "mark": {"type": "rule", "color": "red"},
      "encoding": {"y": {"datum": 0.15, "type": "quantitative"}}
    }
  ]
}
```

In this code, I use a second layer to overlay a rule for a constant value, but it just doesn't show up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. Your top level encoding maps `x` to field `ts`, but `"data": { "values": [] },` does not have any field named `ts`, so the encoding is undefined and no mark is drawn.
2. The `datum` encoding is applied to each entry in the associated dataset, but your dataset has length 0, and so there are no entries. You can use `"data": { "values": [{}] }` instead.

Fixing these two issues gives this ([open in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQgpAE84AJzQBtUABMkmFKlDEkghnAg7Qma+gBMABgcBGfq-cOAbIpDGnSldvAF8FW3sQZzcPLwAOPwCghxCAXTCQZA0AazRbVRw4NBAcNhpZTBAMuFkoNj1ysjyQAA9mgDMaOEE9Yrs-TAKi9ExEUo1zKqVVDq6e4pQlQcLigEcGJAq6QxpSKpCw-UNjU3NLe100jKzckxBl4ZANBkEipTrBNi10DThe6tq9UazRmdwMmAYCDQgVcYiWQzWGy2RkwuyKByuQA)):

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "layer": [
    {
      "data": {
        "values": [
          {"ts": "2021-11-26", "a": 0.16},
          {"ts": "2021-11-28", "a": 0.12}
        ]
      },
      "mark": {"type": "point"},
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "ts", "type": "temporal"},
        "y": {"field": "a", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    },
    {
      "data": {"values": [{}]},
      "mark": {"type": "rule", "color": "red"},
      "encoding": {"y": {"datum": 0.15, "type": "quantitative"}}
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. One more question. This was a simplified example, and in practice I have more layers that use the same encoding, hence I would like to keep it at top level. Ia that possible?